# Git-For-Windows not reading my self-signed SSL certificate

Tags: windows, git, certificate-store, git-for-windows

I deploy my CA cert via GPO into Trusted Root Certification Authorities, which I can see is deployed to my client machines. I know this part is working as Chrome no longer moans when browsing to sites using my signed SSL certs.

However, when I try and git clone or push to any repositories behind an SSL cert signed by this CA, git-for-windows bawlks and says this:

> schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error
>   (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation
>   for the certificate.

As you can see, I've got schannel enabled, but git-for-windows is clearly not reading my CA cert from the Certificate Store in Windows. Any one know how I make gfw read from the Certificate Store in Windows? I can't manually copy this cert onto all my Windows clients, that'd take forever.

Perhaps worth noting I'm using multiple Samba 4 instances as Domain Controllers, but I don't have access to Windows Server tools such as AS Certificate Services.

nb. I know I can disable tls verification, but that surely defeats the purpose.

Comment: It *does* read it, which is why it tries to check it for revocation. Since it's self-signed by some unknown machine, it can't be checked. Since you use a GPO though you *don't* need a self-signed certificate, AD's Certificate services can issue proper certificates validated and trusted by the domain itself. You don't need to manually deploy them with a GPO.

Comment: This AD is deployed via Samba, not Windows Server, so I don't have access to the Certificate Services.

Comment: Don't do that then. If you want Active Directory's services, why use *Samba*? And yes, I had the extremely unfortunate and painful experience of working in a company where people didn't want to use (actually, learn about) M$ products forcing everyone to login multiple times with the same password, have trouble accessing file shares etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't just unpick a Samba AD setup and replace it with Windows Server. The CA certs are self signed and work correctly elsewhere, so I'm not sure what I'm missing when it comes to git functions. Can the revocation be safely ignored in a local setup? No-one is required to login multiple times anywhere. Samba functions perfectly fine as an Active Directory replacement on the whole. https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller#Introduction

Comment: On the other hand, why not install a certificate server *somewhere* and use that to create and validate the certificates? The problem isn't Git. The problem is that the certificate was created pointing to something no other machine knows about. It doesn't matter how you distribute it, applications that use it will have no way of validating it.

Comment: It's not a Smaba AD setup, it's just Samba. That's why there are issues right now. In a proper domain the *controllers* are the local roots and can be used to check for revocation (not just validation). Since there are no controllers, each machine has to act like its own root. If *any* code asks for certificate revocation though, that self-signed certificate won't have any information that can be used to check a revocation list

Comment: When I visit development sites which are behind SSL certs signed by this CA cert, Chrome, Firefox, the works, all report the certificates as perfectly acceptable. What's the difference here? I can see the entire certificate chain from Chrome or manually using "openssl s_client -showcerts -connect address:443"

Comment: Have you tried checking it for revocation? Maybe it's missing information on the certificate, maybe it's the machines that look at incorrect or non-existent revocation lists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199631/discussion-between-schodemeiss-and-panagiotis-kanavos).